# C# Form class won't write to text file

Tags: c#, class, variables, text

My class in a C# Form project won't write to a text file.  I'm tying to take text from another text file and write it to another file but when I check my "Write.txt" file there is nothing written on the file.

My class code that needs fixing:

```
  public static void cal()
    {
        if (level == 6)
        {
            System.IO.StreamWriter tw;
            tw = new StreamWriter("Write.txt");

            string health5 = File.ReadLines("Loons.txt").Skip(31).Take(1).First();
            health = decimal.Parse(health5);
            tw.WriteLine(health5);

            string damage5 = File.ReadLines("Loons.txt").Skip(32).Take(1).First();
            damage = decimal.Parse(damage5);
            tw.WriteLine(damage5);

            string speed5 = File.ReadLines("Loons.txt").Skip(33).Take(1).First();
            speed = decimal.Parse(speed5);
            tw.WriteLine(speed5);

            string time5 = File.ReadLines("Loons.txt").Skip(34).Take(1).First();
            time = decimal.Parse(time5);
            tw.WriteLine(time5);
            tw.Close();
            tw.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

How can I get it to write the variable?

Comment: Firstly, you should be using a `using` statement to make sure that the resource is always disposed. (It's not clear why you're declaring the variable separately to initializing it either, but that's a different matter.) Have you debugged through this? Are you sure you're looking in the right directory for the file?

Comment: Where are health, damage, speed and time declared, all I see is health5, damage5, speed5 and time5 declarations.

Comment: If you don't get an exception then you can be sure that the file was written.  Just not where you *think* it is being written.   A very standard bug, you are looking at an old copy of the file, the new one is stored in a different directory.  *Always* use full path names, use Environment.GetFolderPath() so you can reliably store them in AppData.

Comment: Tip: Whenever I do some file stuff and am not sure yet where to eventually put it I still give as absolute path my temp directory. This way, at least I know where to look for the file.